# iPhone 4s not receiving iBeacon notifications in background

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

iPhone 4s not receiving iBeacon notifications in background.

I have an app that acts as an `iBeacon` and also scans for them.Using an iPhone 5, iPad Air, and iPad mini Retina I get the `notifications` in the foreground and background.

One of our testers has a 4s and apparently only gets `notifications` in the foreground. It can apparently take up to 15 minutes to deliver the notification and apparently it is not arriving in that time frame. For background modes I have location updates, external accessory communication, uses bluetooth LE accessories and acts as bluetooth le accessory.

I also have `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay` set to `YES`.  What is weird is that it does work as expected on all devices so I am curious if anyone else has seen this issue.

Currently I am confirming that:

> a) It is for sure a 4s.
>
> b) That background use is on for that app.
>
> c) Will get a 4s tomorrow to try hands on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really tricky to test, so I would try it yourself and not rely on reports of a "tester".  When you get your 4s, if you do not see background notifications in 15 min of an iBeacon showing up, try hitting the shoulder button and verifying you get it right away.

If this does not help, I'd suggest:

1. Post your code that produces this problem so others can try.
2. Try to run the code in the github project referenced in my blog post [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html) and see if that code triggers within 15 min.

If the code in (2) works, there might be an issue in how you are setting it up.

Comment: I can't post this particular code because its a clients.  Point 2 - will do once I get a 4S in my hands.  What I am looking for is if anyone else has noticed this with a 4S or if background notifications come through fine on a 4S, even within that 15 minute window. Given that it works fine on all other BLE devices it seems odd that it would have to be coded slightly different for a 4S

Comment: Now that I have the phone I can confirm it was the tester.  It did occur, just took about 12 minutes, which is good as I had already seen your article and told them it could take up to 15 minutes.

Comment: @davidyoung, I've never seen a beacon notification take as long as 15 minutes. What is your experience in terms of distribution of notification delays? Most notifications seem to come in within 10 seconds or so of turning on the beacon, even when the device is locked.)

Comment: @Duncan - They are fairly fast on an iPhone 5 - but definitely slower to arrive on a 4s. I suspect the 4s doesn't scan as frequently.

Comment: @Codezy, a 4s is my primary development phone, and I've never seen a delay anywhere near 15 minutes. Delays of >1 minute are rare.

Comment: @Duncan - Is this with the app in the background and the phone locked?

Comment: @duncan-c, I primarily develop on a 4S. I have witnessed two modes of operation, one where iOS gives detections every 4 minutes and another where it gives a detection every 15 minutes.    These long detection times are only when no app is ranging in the foreground.  When ranging in the foreground, detection times are around 1s.   A colleague with a iPhone 5 reports never seeing delays of > 1 min in the background.  I plan to do comprehensive tests on his device.  Unfortunately, if there is variance depending on some internal state of iOS, this will be very hard to track down.

Comment: @davidgyoung please publish if you have results.

Comment: @Codezy, can you please tell me what type of iBeacon you are using for the test where it took 12 minutes to detect in the background?  Do you know its transmission frequency?

Comment: It's an iPhone acting as an iBeacon using CBPeripheralManager and passing nil to peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower

Comment: Interesting.  I have been digging into this over the past few days and I am seeing background detection delays on iBeacon transmitters that send out advertisements less frequently than 1.1 Hz.  Usually iOS devices send out advertisements at 30x per sec.  I wish I could tell you an easy way to measure the transmission frequency of your iPhone when acting as an iBeacon.  Unfortunately this is not easy to do.